# ProgressDialogue is not dismissing or cancelling at all

Tags: java, android, progressdialog

I have shown one progress bar on API call like below :

```
 // prepare for a progress bar dialog
 progressBar = new ProgressDialog(context);
 progressBar.setCancelable(false);
 progressBar.setMessage(context.getResources().getString(R.string.please_wait));
 progressBar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
```

But when I cancel or dismiss the progress dialogue created above it has no  effect.

```
progressBar.cancel();
progressBar.dismiss();
```

Above two calls are in success & failure callback methods :

```
@Override
public void success(RockAPI.CallResult result) {
    progressBar.cancel();
    progressBar.dismiss();
    ....
}

@Override
public void failure(RockAPI.CallResult result) {
    progressBar.cancel();
    progressBar.dismiss();
    ......
}
```

I debugged the application at both success & failure points these lines of code getting executed but still progress dialogue persists. I have checked all the code there is no other place from which this progress bar `show()` is getting called. Its the same progress dialogue but just not getting canceled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create such alike functions and call whenever needed..

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog;


public void showPD(String message) {
    if (progressDialog == null) {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
        //progressDialog.setProgressNumberFormat(null);
        //progressDialog.setProgressPercentFormat(null);
        //progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        //progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progressDialog.setMessage(message);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        progressDialog.show();
    }
}

public void hidePD() {
    if (progressDialog != null) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        progressDialog = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting cancelable as false so dont call progressBar.cancel(). Skip that and directly call progressBar.dismiss(). It should work. If it doesnt we will dig deeper.

Comment: This is still not working for me.Do you have any idea or suggestions that what else i can recheck here?

Comment: One thing that might cause this is if you are creating more than one instance of youy progress dialog. Check if progressBar = new ProgressDialog(context); is called only once in your code

Answer (score 0):

Use true instead of false in your `setCancelable` and it  will work  .

```
progressBar.setCancelable(true);
```